# Can I include options in ssh authorized_keys file from another file?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Basically, I want an RBAC solution to managing authorized_keys configs.

We have many users who use SSH tunnels into our systems through a bastion host/jump box. Each of these users has their authorized_keys file on the bastion host managed with certain permitopen="host:port",no-pty, etc options to limit their access. Many of these users have the same configuration because they have the same role. I'd like to do something like this as the line with their key:

```
include="/etc/ssh/authorized_keys_options/rolename" public_key comment
```

This would allow me to manage roles rather than individual users and ease my monotony. Can it be done?

I'm open to a different approach to managing the bastion host configuration.

Comment: You could have a look at the `sshd_config` option called `AuthorizedKeysCommand` as it allows you to run a program at connection time to output a line in the same format as those in the authorized_keys file. Such progrqm could be a wrapper on top of user authorized_keys file by prepending the shared option you need.

Comment: That's an interesting avenue to investigate. Thanks @PatrickMevzek